# Can this F# byte array -> string slicer be made faster? (F#)

Tags: f#

I want to slice a byte array that represents null terminated strings and return a string sequence.

Test data:

```
let a: byte array = [| 65uy;73uy;76uy;74uy;73uy;0uy;73uy;74uy;0uy;72uy;75uy;72uy;0uy;0uy;73uy;75uy; |]
```

The slicer:

```
let toTextSlices (x: byte array) (separator: byte) : string seq =
    let mutable last = 0
    let length = x.Length - 1
    
    let rec findSeparator position : int =
        if position < length && x[position] <> separator then findSeparator (position + 1)
        else position
        
    seq {
        while (last < length) do
            let l = findSeparator last
            if x[last] <> separator then
                yield Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (x[last .. l])
            last <- l + 1
    }
```

Getting the output:

```
toTextSlices a 0uy
```

The output:

```
[| "AILJI"; "IJ"; "HKH"; "IK" |]
```

The arrays are quite large, ~10mb sometimes, so I'd like to avoid memory allocations and get the best performance.

How can this be improved?

Comment: What do you need to do with each slice in the sequence after it is yielded?  There are options in more recent .NET Core versions like `Span<char>` or `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` that might allow you to reuse pooled memory, but if you are going to eventually do a `ToString()` you're going to get the allocation anyway.

Comment: If you can pre-allocate a buffer to fill in, then yes, this can probably be made faster since you won't need to generate a sequence.

Comment: Related issue in dotnet/runtime repo https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/934

Comment: Also, do you expect the individual slices to be small, large, or of any arbitrary size?

Comment: Each slice is around 500 +/-200 bytes long

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler and perhaps faster:

```ml
let toTextSlices (bytes : byte array) (separator : byte) =
    Text.Encoding.ASCII
        .GetString(bytes)
        .Split(char separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

It does allocate a large string, but only once and 10MB isn't much memory these days (and it works fine if the separator is `0uy`).